# Jquery cycle plugin, slideshow speed

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I have this jQuery slide show from JQuery Cycle plugin....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load', function() {  
    var img_widths = [];
    var imgs = $(".pics").find("img");
    imgs.each(function() {
      img_widths.push($(this).width());
      $(this).attr("width", $(this).width());
    });
});
$('.pics').cycle('fade');
</script>
```

Its been adjusted a bit, but I was wondering if anyone knew how to make it go fast or slower? adjust the speed, I looked at a tutorial of it on the website of the plug, but it didnt work.

Comment: Have you read the options documentation (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)?

Comment: Your question can be answered by simply reading the documentation at the Cycle website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes 1 second to fade, at 8 second intervals...

```
$(".pics").cycle({
    fx:'fade',
    speed:1000,
    timeout:8000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to the one bellow, you have to pass options to the cycle command:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load', function() {  
    var img_widths = [];
    var imgs = $(".pics").find("img");
    imgs.each(function() {
      img_widths.push($(this).width());
      $(this).attr("width", $(this).width());
    });
});
$('.pics').cycle({
                    fx:     'fade',
                    speed:   1000
                 });
</script>
```

You can update the speed variable (**it uses ms**), you've several other options that you can use, i like to use [this jquery cycle option reference](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pics').cycle({
    fx : 'fade',
    speed: 1000
});
```

Just adjust the speed number.